# Verify Twitter Login Credentials

Tags: ios, twitter

I am using TWTRLogInButton to enable users to log into my iOS app using their Twitter credentials.  This means that once the user authorizes my app via Twitter, they can log in without re-entering their Twitter login credentials.

Once a user has logged in using Twitter, I'd like to set up a settings panel in the app that requires users to re-authenticate using Twitter.  In other words, I want them to enter their Twitter username and password in order to access the settings.  (This is because my app is sometimes used in a public settings, and some users would like to disable sharing directly to Twitter from the app.  The settings panel would authenticate the user first to determine whether to disable sharing to Twitter throughout the rest of the app).

What is the best way to re-authenticate Twitter users in objective-c?  Should I be using the REST API?